# Sharepoint Lists , Picture Library and jQuery slideshow

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010

I have one Announcement list in my home page and I have 3 members and they have a contribute permission level.

I want each member of them be able to add an announcement so that if member One add an announcement he can edit his own announcement but member Two cannot edit it. In the same time, if member Two can add an announcement and edit his own announcement, Member One cannot edit it, what settings to do to behave like this?

The same in the picture library: I want each member add his own pictures without any one being able to edit what the other member add.

I tried to create a folder for each member and set permissions to them, but it does not work, and the if I stop inheritance in that folder, the anonymous cannott view anything added to these folders and the same in picture library: whatever added to these folders does not show up.

Should I be able to create an Image Jquery slideshow in some way, such that each member can add, edit and delete only what he will add and only views what others add?

Any other suggestions are welcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating a custom list template, set the `SecurityBits` of the [ListTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms462947) element to 12 (Users can read all items, but only edit their own items).

> SecurityBits: Defines the item-level permissions in the list for users with sufficient permission to read or edit list items. The SecurityBits attribute contains a 2-digit string. The first digit in the string controls the read access; the second digit in the string controls the edit access.

If you are using out of the box list templates, you can change individual list instances by setting the [WriteSecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.writesecurity%28v=office.14%29.aspx) property to 2.

You can set this property manually by going to List Settings > Advanced Settings and selecting "Create items and edit items that were created by the user" in the Item-level Permissions section.

Comment: Thank you Rich , I did what u said , it solve my issue but i faced another issue is that the annonymous user cant view the items in the list , so how i can make them able to view the item without prompting them to enter username and password , any idea !

Comment: Anonymous access is a separate issue, so I suggest asking it as a brand new question. If this answers your first question, please click the up arrow and checkmark on the left hand side. thanks.